# User-input string into array, causing buffer overflow

Tags: c, arrays, user-input, c-strings

I am quite new to C, and I'm working on a program right now where I am asking the user to input character arrays(strings) in the form of program names, store these names in an array then pass this array to another function.

Right now, the latest way I've attempted to achieve this is with a dynamically allocated array, as I don't know what the user may want to input, and here's how I'm doing that:

```
char *process;
process = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i+1));
```

I then go on to request the user's input and confirm their input with `printf`:

```
printf("Enter process name: ");
scanf("%79s", &process); // take input, load into array
// fgets(process, sizeof(ARRAY_SIZE), stdin);
printf("You entered: %s\n", process[i]);
```

I've tried both `scanf()` and `fgets()`, where `scanf()` actually works and `fgets()` causes the program to jump completely past my `printf` statement and goes on to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    printf("process = %s\n", process[i]);
```

Which is where the program terminates with a `Segmentation Fault`. I understand this is due to the user input overrunning the buffer allocated.

In `gdb` when printing the value of process, it's filled with garbage (which from my understanding is how C initializes an array before values are added). Right after `scanf("%79s", &process)`, process shows my input added at the beginning of the garbage instead of replacing the garbage. My question is how do I "empty" my array so I quit overrunning the buffer? Been at this for three days trying several methods, and I think it has to do with me missing some detail of how to properly initialize my array. I have `#define ARRAY_SIZE 80` which should be more than adequate to get this functioning, though may not suffice in later implementations.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to tell us what is `i` and its value but yet `scanf("%79s", &process);` is wrong and has to be `scanf("%79s", process);`

Comment: You have bits and pieces of code that don't look right. You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will be helpful for everybody to see what and where your code is not quite right.

Comment: I initialized `i` as `i = ARRAY_SIZE;`. Why would I do `scanf("%79s", process)` as opposed to my original version, though? I thought I would want to load the input at the beginning address of `process`.

I'll pull together an MCVE for you guys, as I have several other functions that work fine in the program but make it quite long.

Comment: K&R 2nd. ed is ANSI C89/ISO C90 compliant and those are a subset of ISO C99 and C11. C89 is the last standard that is defined by ANSI rather than ISO.  If you are using the 1978 1st edition of K&R then you really are in trouble, but I doubt that and do not see what that preamble has to do with your question in any case?

Comment: @TomJ `scanf("%79s", &process)` is writing in the `process`  object not in the buffer `process` is pointing to.

Comment: Is your question about why it seg-faults, or how to accept a variable and non-deterministic amount of input characters?  Answers to both have been posted, but you have not explicitly asked any question.  You have said what you are trying to do (but your solution won't actually do what you say you are trying to do), and you have said that it seg-faults.  You would learn more by looking at why it seg-faults because you have some fundamental misunderstandings, the solution to arbitrary length input is far less of a problem, and as you can see cumbersome to overcome (and probably not necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `process` is already a pointer, `&process` has type `char**` and is a pointer to the pointer variable, not the pointer to the allocated buffer.

`sizeof(char)` always equals 1 by definition, so is unnecessary in the `malloc()` call.  If you use `scanf()` it should be thus:

```
scanf( "%79s", process ) ;
```

but because the length is hard-coded in the string and not related to either `i` or `ARRAY_SIZE` it is better to use `fgets()`, but you use a length argument `sizeof(ARRAY_LEN)` which is the same as `sizeof(int)`; you meant just `ARRAY_LEN`.  In this case the the allocation need not have been `i + 1` because `fgets()` inserts the nul within the size given, so:

```
fgets( process, ARRAY_SIZE, stdin ) ;
```

Moreover it is hardly necessary to use `malloc()` for a fixed length array; you are not setting the array to fit the input, but restricting the input to fit the array.  That being the case then I would suggest:

```
char process[ARRAY_SIZE] ;
printf( "Enter process name: " ) ;
fgets( process, sizeof(process), stdin ) ;
```

For the output of the input data character-by-character, you need the `%c` format specifier, not `%s`:

```
for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ )
    printf( "process = %c\n", process[i] ) ;
```

but that will print unused, unitialised characters from the array, so more likely:

```
for( i = 0; process[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    printf( "process = %c\n", process[i] ) ;
```

or since `process` is a nul terminated string, simply:

```
printf("process = %s\n", process ) ;
```

So ultimately all you need is:

```
char process[ARRAY_SIZE] ;
printf( "Enter process name: " ) ;
fgets( process, sizeof(process), stdin ) ;
printf("process = %s\n", process ) ;
```

Comment: beautiful. that worked like a charm. I was having a misunderstanding in how to actually get the data from `stdin` to the array, and that answered it perfectly. Thanks @Clifford, you clarified a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *process;
    int i = 0;//number of input character;
    size_t size;//Allocated size
    int ch;

    //process = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i+1));//+1 for '\0'
    size = 16;//Initial size
    process = malloc(size);//cast don't need in C

    printf("Enter process name: ");//fflush(stdout);
    while((ch = getchar())!=EOF && ch != '\n'){
        if(i == size -1){//-1 for NUL('\0')
            char *temp = realloc(process, size += 16);//expand size
            if(temp==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to malloc\n");
                free(process);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            process = temp;//successfully extended update
        }
        process[i++] = ch;
    }
    process[i] = 0;
    printf("process = %s\n", process);//type of process[i] is `char`
    free(process);
    return 0;
}
```